# SignInActivity attribute stopped working?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an automated workbook to keep our Azure environment clean from stale Guest account.
For this I use the SigninActivity attribute in Azure, through Graph.
This has worked fine for about a month, but suddenly, last week, it stopped working, and when I as for the specific URI, I do not get any results in return. If I remove the specific SignInActiviy attribute, the query works fine and returns all Guest users.
But I need the SingInActivity data for my workbook to work.
Anyone have the same issue, or have any update?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for delayed response.

Sharing my findings in case if anyone come across similar issue.

I was able to get Signinactivity by using https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,userPrincipalName,signInActivity

Returned only on `$select`. Supports `$filter` (`eq`, `ne`, `NOT`, `ge`, `le`) but, not with any other filterable properties. Note: Details for this property require an Azure AD Premium P1/P2 license and the **AuditLog.Read.All permission**.

Note: There's a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#azure-ad-activity-reports) with retrieving this property.

References:

[signInActivity resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signinactivity?view=graph-rest-beta) &
[user resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties)

Comment: for me this URL is not wokring - `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=id,mail,displayName,signInActivity&$filter=signInActivity ne null`